# Can one leave the Gaza strip permanently?

Tags: israel, palestine, citizenship, asylum, gaza

I don't really know where to put this question and as it is somewhat a political decision I will ask it here.

Based on this [Wikipedia Article](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_freedom_of_movement) it seems like one can't really leave the Gaza strip. But all these articles are about "freedom of movement" and traveling between Israel and the Gaza strip for medical help.

Assume that I am living in the Gaza strip. Assume further that I would want to flee from there due to the warlike situation. Would (especially) Israel/ Egypt/Jordan grant me asylum due to my situation? Could I get a regular citizenship in Israel if I am willing to never return to the Gaza strip?

Would Israel accept something like that? I didn't find anything on this topic - only on the topic of traveling between those places.

Comment: Given that it's in Israel's best interest for there to be fewer Palestinians, I'd be surprised if they didn't let people up and leave.

Comment: I would think that way too! But I couldn't find any (reliable) sources on this topic. As a palestine you could improve your Standard of Living dramatically as Israel is a highly advanced country. And Israel would profit by having a good image, reduction of people that are potentially against them and a good integration of following generations.

Comment: No, you can't enter Israel from Gaza now that Gaza is no longer part of Israel (unless you have the proper documentation, which is difficult for non-Jews, especially Arabs, to get). You can't enter Egypt or any other country either, just like you can't just come from any country to the US. Unfortunately, international law does force countries to accept "refugees," but don't think that people will cheerfully give you citizenship for "promising that you won't return to Gaza."

Comment: Some far-right extremists in Israel call for "transfer", which is Palestinians either being encouraged to, or being forced to, leave the Palestinian territories. For an example of the former, see http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2715466/Israeli-official-calls-concentration-camps-Gaza-conquest-entire-Gaza-Strip-annihilation-fighting-forces-supporters.html#ixzz3AHCmvyBU However, neighbouring countries have mostly had a history of not granting asylum to Palestinians.

Comment: @Haini Are you asking practically or legally under some country's law? If you got out of Gaza you may be able to flee to another country that would grant asylum (almost certainly NOT Egypt, Israel, or Jordan), but neither Egypt nor Israel AFAIK have a mechanism in place to allow Gazans to leave for non-medical reasons.

Comment: @Avi: It's more of a practical question I guess. But as you have stated in your comment: You can't even leave Gaza if you have no plans to return and you Want to live peacefully in another country. So if I live in country A and want to move to country B with my familiy to find work there - this scenario wouldn't be possible for anyone who lives in Gaza, did I get that right? Even if I would be highly qualified, had enough money and so on?

Comment: @haini maybe there is a way to do it but I don't know what that would be. Getting out of Gaza requires going through Israel, Egypt, or the blockade, which block movement but in extenuating circumstances.

Comment: @Shahar: The Gaza Strip was _never_ part of Israel.

Comment: If you can travel from Gaza to Svalbard, you can live and work there indefinitely: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Svalbard

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This article](https://www.jpost.com/Middle-East/Palestinians-reveal-emigration-statistics-for-first-time) cites a Palestinian Central Bureau of Statistics (PCBS) study that deals with the West Bank and Gaza emigration:

> about 7,000 people leave the West Bank and Gaza every year, mostly for
> economic opportunities rather than to escape the conflict with Israel,
> according to the Palestinian Central Bureau of Statistics (PCBS).
>
> The study was done in conjunction with MEDSTAT, a European Union
> project aiding Mediterranean countries with statistical research. It
> was paid for by the Palestinian Authority. Some 15,000 households were
> questioned in face to face interviews, including 5,000 in the Gaza
> Strip.

So, there is a way for these 7000 people/year to leave those areas, if this figure is accurate.

However, the article does not deal with how they manage to emigrate. [This article](https://www.jewishpress.com/news/eye-on-palestine/investigative-report-mass-emigration-from-gaza-threatens-future-of-pa/2019/05/12/) dives into more details about this:

> Gaza’s younger and educated population is leaving the Strip in search
> of a better future in Europe while risking their lives in a dangerous
> journey running through Africa’s countries.

The same article only mentions Belgium as a country that is accepting these immigrants:

(..) Belgium, where a large community of over 22,000 Gazans is rapidly forming.
(..) Obtaining the proper papers in Belgium is also a tedious process,

This confirms that Israel is not a destination country and this is also confirmed by [this Quora answer](https://qr.ae/TWND3m) that says that receiving Israeli citizenship is very rare:

> It is possible, in very extreme circumstances, such as having an
> Israeli spouse under certain conditions or based on particular
> services to the Israeli government (and even those situations are
> often contravened). However, most Palestinians cannot gain Israeli
> citizenship, especially if they were born and raised outside of
> Israel/Palestine.

Comment: So many years after asking this question and then two answers and an open bounty. 
I think your answer covers the question very well, but it would be interesting to have a better source than a Quora answer wrt to the Israeli citizenship :-)

Comment: @Haini - yes, I am also not happy with the references. The other two seem to be from Israeli which have some bias (naturally). I have also found the article cited by `Time4Tea`, but could not find other source to back up the information. I will try to find more information about MEDSTAT which should be less biased since is EU related.

Answer (score 4):

[This article](https://unitedwithisrael.org/gazan-woman-runs-for-office-in-belgium-plans-to-defend-palestinian-refugees/), from about a month ago, describes a Palestinian woman from Gaza who moved to Belgium and is now running for office in the Belgian parliament. So, the example seems to prove that it is physically and practically possible for someone to leave the Gaza strip.

Comment: This person studied European universities and in her CV she speaks about her "multicultural origins". She almost certainly has and had another passport that enables her to travel freely.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some options:

- Canada has [announced that it will give visas to Gazans with relatives in Canada](https://news.google.com/articles/CBMiMmh0dHBzOi8vd3d3Lmpwb3N0LmNvbS9pbnRlcm5hdGlvbmFsL2FydGljbGUtNzc5MTI50gEA?hl=en-IL&gl=IL&ceid=IL%3Aen). So, if you are a Gazan with relatives in Canada, the answer is yes.
- Russia has [issued a decree allowing foreign nationals who fight for Russia in Ukraine to obtain Russian citizenship for themselves and their families.](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/putin-offers-citizenship-foreigners-who-fight-russia-2024-01-04/). So, if you or someone from your family can fight, the answer is yes.
- Previously, Russia has [accepted 40 Palestinian refugees from Gaza](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/middle-east/40-palestinian-refugees-arrive-in-russias-karachay-cherkess-region/3088866), and this group is said to be the "first", so probably there will be more. I could not understand how exactly these 40 were selected, and what should a Gazan do to be included in the next groups.
- If you can physically travel from Gaza to Svalbard, [you can live and work there indefinitely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Svalbard).
- According to [this link](https://www.gofundme.com/f/help-family-in-gaza-leave-palestine), for $5,000 per person, you can bribe an Egyptian official to let you pass the border to Egypt.
- There are [some countries in which you can legally buy citizenship](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/83562/2254), though the price is much higher than $5,000 per person.

Comment: Seriously? This is as biased as your previous Qs and As. You are sowing Gazans are doing fine because they can go serve as mercenaries for Russia? Even if suggesting that wasn't abhorrent enough, don't forget they first have to cross the border in some way. If they could, they could of course apply for a refugee status in many countries in Eurpe. But getting there is the problem. The whole purpose of this ansew is to support Smotrich, Gvir and Netanyahu.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I did not say that "Gazans are doing fine". On the contrary, I know they are in trouble and look for potential solutions. Regarding your last sentence: would you say that helping Ukraininans find a refuge outside Ukraine is "supporting Putin"?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава "If they could, they could of course apply for a refugee status in many countries in Eurpe" -- I am not so sure about that.  If there were European countries willing to accept a substantial number of Gazan refugees, it should not have been difficult to arrange a maritime humanitarian corridor to bring them there. The problem is that no European country has agreed.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize other answers: if you are able to get out, there are places that will let you stay under certain conditions.

I would add that there are also places that don't want you, but where your chances of not getting caught and deported are quite good.

And if you're wealthy enough there are countries where you can buy citizenship.

Comment: If you manage to set your foot in a western country and throw out your documents your chances are quite good as well, at least until the UK’s Rwanda deportation plans become mainstream.

Answer (score -3):

How permanent is permanent? Look at the Jews, they were forcibly dispersed from Palestine by the Romans after a failed uprising two thousand years ago, and during that time there was very little Jewish presence in Palestine, up until when the Israeli state was established under the aegis of two super-powers, the British and then the USA.

Gazans are loath to migrate from Gaza en-masse permanently as this is simply ethnic cleansing by another name. At present, there is a tiny trickle abroad, mostly for economic opportunities. The Israelis know this and simply do not want to go to the trouble of economically helping a few Gazans when their main aim is to get rid of all them. This is why Netanyahu is exploiting the present crisis to "voluntarily" offer a migration path to the Congo although the Congo is denying such talks have taken place.