# Are there countries that allow foreigners to buy citizenship for a fixed fee?

Tags: citizenship

Most countries are quite selective in accepting new citizens. Even in [Svalbard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Svalbard), which is very liberal in letting people live and work there, cannot in general get Norwegian citizenship.

Are there countries which are more liberal in this sense, and allow every person, from everywhere in the world,  that pays the government a certain fixed fee, to become a citizen?  This could be a good source of income for sparsely-populated countries.

If not: are there countries (other than in Svalbard) that allow every person that pays a fee to get a permanent visa, so that they can live and work there indefinitely?

- One example I found for the latter is [a condition to get a Green Card to the USA](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/green-card-eligibility-categories): "Have invested or are actively in the process of investing at least $1,050,000 (or $800,000 in a targeted employment area or infrastructure project) in a new commercial enterprise in the U.S. which will create full-time positions for at least 10 qualifying employees". Though you cannot just pay $1,050,000 to get a green card - you must invest it in a particular way.

Comment: Every country is going to have requirements relating to criminal history, so none will extend this privilege to "every person."

Comment: *you must invest it in a particular way* => if you have a million in cash, there's plenty of companies happy to do the legwork on your behalf to satisfy the formal requirements. So for all intents and purposes it _can_ be treated as a fixed fee.

Comment: Search for "golden visa". See e.g. https://www.henleyglobal.com/countries You usually can't directly "buy" a citizenship, but you can buy a visa (which in many cases can then lead to citizenship or at least permanent residency)

Comment: @user103496 there are places which actually sell “golden passports”. There’s a bit of a crackdown on the actually useful ones though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **2023**, there are a total of **TWELVE nations** that offer "citizenship for a fee" programs.

1. Antigua & Barbuda [[4](https://cbiindex.com/caribbean-five-and-us-agree-on-six-principles/)]
2. Austria -- [Two year process](https://cbiindex.com/austria/)
3. Cambodia -- Requires knowledge of [Khmer history and language](https://cbiindex.com/cambodia/)
4. Dominica [[4](https://cbiindex.com/caribbean-five-and-us-agree-on-six-principles/)]
5. Egypt
6. Grenada [[4](https://cbiindex.com/caribbean-five-and-us-agree-on-six-principles/)]
7. Jordan
8. Malta
9. Saint Kitts & Nevis [[4](https://cbiindex.com/caribbean-five-and-us-agree-on-six-principles/)]
10. Saint Lucia [[4](https://cbiindex.com/caribbean-five-and-us-agree-on-six-principles/)]
11. Türkiye -- Requires biometrics and direct approval by Erdogan [[7](https://cbiindex.com/turkey/)]
12. Vanuatu -- an island archipelago in the Pacific, see map below.

**Notes**

- A North Macedonia Citizenship program is in development [[8](https://www.henleyglobal.com/citizenship-investment/north-macedonia)]
- Egypt initiated its program in 2020 [[9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4asdP.jpg)]
- Montenegro officially ended its program in December 2022 [[9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4asdP.jpg)]

### Sources

There is an annual [Citizen By Investment index (CBI Index)](https://www.ft.com/partnercontent/the-cbi-index/renowned-cbi-index-launches-its-seventh-edition.html) produced in partnership with the Financial Times of London. There are also [advisory services that assist governments](https://www.henleyglobal.com/services/government-advisory-practice) in the design and operation of investment-related residence and citizenship programs. I used these as sources in addition to the CBI Index.

Keep in mind that countries offering citizenship-for-fee programs vary from year to year, so current data is essential!

> Several countries had programs in place at different times in the past
> that were specifically designed to attract foreign investors in return
> for citizenship. These include Ireland, whose program was terminated
> in 2001, Belize (until 2002), Grenada (terminated 2001 but reopened in
> 2014), Cape Verde, Seychelles, Slovakia, and several others.
>
> via *[An Introduction to Citizenship by Investment](https://www.henleyglobal.com/citizenship-investment)*

Also, due to Russia's Special Military Operation, some of the TWELVE nations listed above do not accept Russian Federation or Belarus citizens. Likewise, due to various other sanctions, citizens of Iran, North Korea, and Afghanistan are excluded by some but not all programs.

---

Vanuatu is located in the South Pacific Ocean. It was formerly the New Hebrides until it gained its independence from France and the UK in 1980.

[image: 1982 World Factbook map of Vanuatu in the south Pacific Ocean. Vanuatu attained its independence from France and Great Britain in 1980.]

Comment: There are quite a few other countries which allow you to get citizenship in two steps: get residency through investment then get citizenship after a few years of residency. Not as quick and direct as cash-for-passport, but it opens the door to quite a few other “powerful” passports.

Comment: @jcaron Yes, you are correct, but that isn't what the question asked. The sources that I cited provide that information as well.

Answer (score 22):

There are [20 Countries Where You Can Buy Citizenship](https://youthvillage.co.zw/opportunities/20-countries-where-you-can-buy-citizenship/). If you count countries where you can buy 'elite residency', there are even [23 countries](https://www.businessinsider.com/countries-where-you-can-buy-citizenship-residency-or-passport-2018-9).

[image]

Many of these countries were popular among rich Russians, but now, in the context of the conflict in Ukraine, Russians are facing problems in those countries.

Comment: What exactly does "investment" mean? Is it simply a price that you pay the government, or do you actually have to "invest" the money in some local industry?

Comment: @Erel Segal-Halevi Each individual country has conditions for precise investments, which are different for each of these countries.

Comment: Are there countries where there is no "investment" requirements - you can just pay a fee to the government and get citizenship?

Comment: @Erel Segal-Halevi I could give the exact conditions for each of the 23 countries, mentioned in that link, but that would make the answer very huge.

Comment: Bulgaria stopped giving citizenship for investments circa mid-2022

Comment: Australia stopped the millionaire visa a while ago, too.

Comment: In the US, marrying a citizen is likely much easier than the $500K investment method. As long as you can prove that it's a legitimate relationship (not just a "green card marriage"), it only takes 3 years and little financial cost.

Comment: If you're including programs that have been "suspended" for a decade, **are** doesn't seem to be the right verb.

Comment: Also, this list doesn't include Vanuatu which would probably be my choice https://www.globalcitizensolutions.com/vanuatu-citizenship-by-investment/

Comment: Thanks! Latvia is the cheapest - only 35 thousand Euros.

Comment: Estonia is another nation; for a million Euros, you can get Estonian residency, which will permit citizenship after residency and a language test.

Comment: This answer is outdated and incorrect. Even though it was accepted, I will provide an answer to the question, which is "Are there countries which allow every person, from everywhere in the world, that pays the government a certain fixed fee, to become a citizen?" It is a decision by @ErelSegal-Halevi whether to consider my answer or not.

Comment: This claims 20 countries, but it is unclear if the evidence supports that claim. Which of these countries are the 20?  [Australia offers a 5 year visa](https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/visas/getting-a-visa/visa-listing/business-innovation-and-investment-188/significant-investor-stream) but not citizenship (without going through longer processes).